# Search indexing of AngularJS application in Java

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, seo, snapshot

I have AngularJS application already in production and I need to make it Google-friendly. I have read about Ajax crawling mechanism and I have following two problems:

**1.** Since I have backend written in Java, I have tried HtmlUnit to make static snapshots, but it didn't work well with AngularJS. How can I serve snapshots of my AngularJS pages using Java?

**2.** As I have mentioned, application is already published and it uses simple hash without !. E.g.: /#/about, /#/home. Is it possible to keep this scheme? Change to /#!/ would require modifications of all links and would break all existing links (posted on web).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SEO is always an issue with single-page application.

I suggest you make a quick implementation of Phantom.js to display already rendered page to google bots. Check out [this link](http://backbonetutorials.com/seo-for-single-page-apps/) for more informations.

Phantom.js will be a gateway to which you redirect every indexing bot request, it will then render your app like a normal user will do, and then send back the rendered page to the bot.

Also, it would be better to change your `/#/` to only `/`, it's better for your users and also SEO. You just need to redirect every request to the index.html page and to use '/#/' as fallback for old browser which doesn't support pushState.

You also have some paid solution like https://prerender.io/ which works beautifuly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I wanted to handle this situation in Java, but since I haven't found any working solution I implemented node.js/express script based on the sample from your first url. Also I have switched to html5 pushstate. I hope that it will work.